# selenium - locate a href link - Unable to find element with link text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

[image]

I getting below error - if I use `linktext()` to locate **specifications** link

Error :

```
Unable to find element with link text == Specifications
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the *HTML* you have shared incase `linktext()` shows error as:

```
Error : Unable to find element with link text == Specifications
```

As an alternative you may need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `linkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Specifications"))).click();
  ```
- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("td.subtabTxtNsel>a.subtabTxtNsel[tag='a']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//td[@class='subtabTxtNsel']/a[@class='subtabTxtNsel' and contains(.,'Specifications')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: thanks working with linktext and xpath , not working with css selector , how can we identify , at when we have to use  webdriverwait() function , please sugguest

Comment: @priya As per the HTML you have provided the element attribute contained _JavaScript_. So naturally the element is represented by a _JavaScript_ which may be refreshed/edited by a _JS_. hence you need to wait for the _JS_ to load the element properly and to achieve that you have to use `webdriverwait()` function.

Comment: hello today when I ran linktext code with WebDriverWait , its not working getting error org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.partialLinkText: Specifications (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.linkText: Specifications (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using **specifications**  but it is **Specifications**.
Just with capital **S** , it should be working fine.

You can use **explicit wait**, something like :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Specifications"))).click();
```

OR with **partial link Text** :

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Specifications"))).click();
```

If both of them still are not working, then you can try this xpath :

```
//td[@class='subtabTxtNsel']/a[text()='Specifications' and @tag='a']
```

Your binding language is not specified, I have provided answer in **JAVA**.

**UPDATE :**

An explicit wait is code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code. The worst case of this is Thread.sleep(), which sets the condition to an exact time period to wait. There are some convenience methods provided that help you write code that will wait only as long as required. WebDriverWait in combination with ExpectedCondition is one way this can be accomplished

Please refer this [link](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) for better understanding.

Comment: thanks its working with explicit wait linktext() , not working with given xpath , please suggest how to identify explicit wait is needed ?

Comment: thanks with linktext () it was working yesterday , but today I got error - org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.partialLinkText: Specifications (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.linkText: Specifications (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)

Comment: what happens when you try with partial link text ?

Comment: tried same error - Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.linkText: Specifications (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval

Comment: Can you tell me your manually steps ? Or is it possible to share the URL of the web application with us here ?

Comment: its just link click, not able to share

Comment: Is that link visible in UI , when you are trying to interact with it ?